# Custom Date Filter using custom column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

How can I achieve the following?

I want to always filter for yesterday's date. **BUT**, if there is no date recorded for yesterday, then filter for friday and saturday instead.

Comment: Add some sample data and your desired results. It's not clear what do you want to achieve. If you don't have data for Thursday then what you want to do?

Comment: Hi msta42a, there will always be data inflow from monday to saturday. What happens is that I will always use data from the day before at work. And I won't be working over the weekends; plus there won't be data inflow on Sunday. Hence, I need to be able to extract info out from last Friday and Saturday on Monday. There are 2 approach I can think of here: 1) Auto detect that yesterday is sunday and extract Fri/Sat data. 2) Auto detect that there are no 'yesterday's date recorded since there is no data inflow; hence use data from Fri/Sat. Hope it gives you a clearer picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you:

First -> check if the current day is Monday
Second -> if so go back 3 days else go back 1
Third -> Sum based on range

```
SumGapSunday = 
var __isMonday = WEEKDAY(TODAY()) = 2 
var __MoveTo = if(__isMonday, TODAY()-3,TODAY()-1)
return
CALCULATE( sum(TableRol[val]), FILTER(TableRol, TableRol[Date] >= __MoveTo && TableRol[Date] < TODAY() ))
```

Comment: do you happen to also know how i can do this?

Comment: If today is the first day of the month, then show only last month's data. If today is NOT the first day of the month, then show only this month's data.

Comment: If you have Calendar table mark as Date table then you can use STARTOFMONTH ( 'Date'[date] ) and compare this with TODAY() and you can build logic on this. If you dont have this kind of table then use DATE ( YEAR(TODAY(), MONTH(TODAY()), 1 ) and compare with TODAY().